# Class attribute incorrect value C++

Tags: c++, class, vector, codeblocks

**EDIT:** *To initialize the position array `m_pos[3]` I set all it's values to 0 in the constructor and then I call from the main function another function called `SetPos()` which only sets the position of the planet in the 3D map:*

```
void SetPos(float x, float z);

void Planet::SetPos(float x, float z)
{
  m_pos[0]=x;
  m_pos[1]=0;
  m_pos[2]=y;
}
```

*Thus, the constructor takes the form:*

```
Planet::Planet()
{
  m_pos[0]=0;
m_pos[1]=0;
m_pos[2]=0;
}
```

Is that a bad way to do it? (by need, i can't set the position directly through the constructor).

**ORIGINAL:**

I've created a class called `Planet` which controles a series of planets (`Planet` object) in a `map`. Each object has an `array pos[3]` which stores the coordinates where the planet must be drawn.

The planets also own a function called `DrawConnections()` which is in charge of drawing lines representing the connections between the actual planet and the other planets. The planets that one planet is connected to are stored in a vector, `std::vector<Planet> connections`.

Since attributes are encapsulated, there's a function in the `Planet` class which returns the position of the planet, called `GetPos(float* pos)`, where `*pos` is a pointer to an array capable of storing the position of the planet.

First things first, those are the prototypes and variable declarations from Planet.h file:

```
public:
void DrawConnections(float radius);
void GetPos(float* position);

private:
float m_pos[3];
std::vector<Planet> m_connection;
```

The function `DrawConnections()` from Planet.cpp looks like this:

```
void Planet::DrawConnections(float radius) //parameter radius controls width of lines
{
float position[3]={0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};   //array storing the position of the planets
                                      //which we are connecting to

//various OpenGl calls go here

glBegin(GL_LINES);                    //begins drawing the lines
for(int i=0;i<m_connection.size();i++)  //for each planet we are connected to, draw a
                                        //line
{
    glVertex3f(m_pos[0],m_pos[1],m_pos[2]);  //draws the first point of the line in the 
                                           //actual planet

    m_connection[i].GetPos(position);    //Gets the position of the planet we connect to

    glVertex3f(position[0],position[1],position[2]);  //draws the second point of the
                                                      //in the planet we connect to
}
glEnd();                                             //ends drawing


//some other OpenGl calls

}
```

The function `GetPos()` from Planet.cpp looks like this:

```
void Planet::GetPos(float* position)
{
    position[0]=m_pos[0];                  //copies the data from the position array to 
    position[1]=m_pos[1];                  //the given pointer
    position[2]=m_pos[2];
}
```

Any planet has x, neither z, 0 coordinate. Each one of them has a set of (x,y,z) coordinates, with x and z always different to 0.

However, some of the calls to `GetPos()` return x and z equal to 0, while others work properly.

This results in many lines going from the planets to the bottom left corner of the screen, without representing any connection. From what I've figured out I think the problem is in the `GetPos()`. However, other similar drawing functions also use `GetPos()` and work perfectly when they're called before the `DrawConnection()` function, but seem to be affected when they're called once `DrawConnections()` has been called It is as if that one was modifying the values of the position array when called and thus disturbing everything else which has to be with the position, including herself.

As an additional information, I'm working with Codeblocks and the MinGW GNU GCC compiler. I appreciate any help that you could give me.

Comment: I would highly recommend using a simple struct for your position vector than a raw float array. Passing pointers around should really be avoided when it's not absolutely needed. In addition, without seeing your constructor for ``planet``, we can't tell if the ``m_pos`` vector is ever properly initialized to reasonable values.

Comment: It's not quite clear what the problem is. Is there anything wrong with `GetPos()` returning x and z values equal to zero? If so, can you check to see if those values were set properly in the object itself (aka: constructor, etc)? Don't forget that you're also working in 3D space, and that the positioning of your OpenGL camera will affect how those lines appear on the screen.

Comment: The problem is that some of the values returned by getPos are 0 for planets whose x,z coordinates aren't equal to 0.

Comment: You store Planets by value in your vector. Do you manipulate them at another spot and possibly push Planets with zero positions?

Comment: Hi Pixelchemist, and thanks for your help. Unfortunately, the problem isn't related to the planets stored in the vector, it is, i still don't know why, related to the coordinates themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do?

```
public:
void DrawConnections(float radius);
const std::vector<float>& GetPos() const {return m_pos;};

private:
std::vector<float> m_pos;
std::vector<Planet> m_connection;
```

Comment: This doesn't necessarily actually solve the problem.